# Limit commands to one channel discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How do I limit a command to one channel? This is what I have. When I use the command it says that the command was invoked correctly but It doesn't send the message.

```
@commands.group(name = "pic", invoke_without_command=True, ignore_extra=False)
    async def picture(self, ctx, *args):
        if ctx.channel == ("bot-test"):
            await ctx.send("pic")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the `name` attribute of the channel, not the `Channel` object itself:

```
@commands.group(name = "pic", invoke_without_command=True, ignore_extra=False)
async def picture(self, ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.name == ("bot-test"):
        await ctx.send("pic")
```